# Execute update if row exists else do insert

Tags: c#, mysql

I have to update a number of rows to a table, if the updating row is not existing in the table I need to insert that row. I cannot use unique key, so no use with **ON duplicate KEY UPDATE**

I have to achieve something like this

```
DECLARE count DOUBLE;
SELECT count(uid) 
INTO   count 
FROM   Table 
WHERE  column1  ='xxxxx'
 AND   column2='xxxxx';

IF (count=0)
THEN
    --peform insert
ELSE
    --perform update
END IF
```

This is for a high performance application.Any ideas? Code level or Query level

FYI : Database is Mysql

Answer (score 3):

You could work with a temporary table.

1. Put your data into a temporary table
2. Do an update of the "other" table via a JOIN
3. Delete the matching data from the temp table
4. Insert the remaining stuff from the temp table into the main table.

This will be faster than doing it record by record if you have loads of data.

Answer (score 1):

That's the store procedure we use, could possibly work for you as well.

```
if not exists (select 1 from Table  where column1  ='xxxxx' AND   column2='xxxxx')
        insert into Table ( column1,column2)
        values ( @xxxx,xxxxx)
else 
    update Table
```

Comment: dang beat me by 30 seconds :) any reason why you do not exists first? I imagine update being a more frequent case.

Comment: :) to be hones we do not have the "else" part, we either insert or not, so to answer your question: yes, probably would be better if it was another way round :)

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
        FROM Table WITH ( UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE )
        WHERE CONDITION) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table SET SOMETHING WHERE CONDITION
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table(Field1,....) VALUES  (Value1,..... )
END
COMMIT TRAN
```

> NOTE: Transaction are very good but using IF EXISTS is not good in case of Insertion/Updation with mulitple queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) or check the cound of a sub select if its > 0 to know if the row exists allready

Answer (score -1):

You may find useful REPLACE statement. Its syntax described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//replace.html).

Comment: REPLACE uses primary and unique keys to match existing records